# How do I use Google Custom Search to find and show words based on input characters on the same page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, search, google-search, google-custom-search

I want to use Google Custom Search to find and show words based on input characters on the same page.
I see some WordPress websites use Google Custom Search like this: they place a search form inside a post that contains many words, and people input some characters like water or retaw, and after clicking on the find button, the page reloads in a new link with the same content and shows the words that characters can make from words inside content.

normal address: website.com/mypost

new address: website.com/mypost/?q=retaw

google find this words from post content and show:
war
raw
water

I searched and found this link: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest, but I can't use it.